# Html Kendo Editor not displaying the top toolbar

Tags: kendo-editor

I have a Kendo Editor, defined as below:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Editor()
          .Name("RestrictionsEditor")
          .Tag("div")
          .Tools(tools => tools
                .Clear()
                .Bold().Italic().Underline().Strikethrough()
                .JustifyLeft().JustifyCenter().JustifyRight().JustifyFull()
                .CreateLink().Unlink()
                .InsertImage()
                .TableEditing()
                .FontColor().BackColor()
          )
          .Value(@<text> This is the Kendo Editor and it has 
                    some anchor tags pointing to external webistes.</text>)
```

When I click inside the editor, The top toolbar for font formatting is not showing. I want to show the top toolbar when user clicks inside the editor and then hide the toolbar when user clicks outside the editor.  Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To show hide the toolbar you first need to set the toolbar to hidden by default, then implement the select and blur events to show and hide the toolbar.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/chrustlesstulip/7fqnthmx/) is a fiddle that implements this in JavaScript.

For your MVC implementation you will need to add script tags to you page and attached the events after the editor is initialized.
Something like this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

  //hide toolbar by default
  $("#RestrictionsEditor").closest(".k-editor").find(".k-editor-toolbar").hide();

  //bind the select event
    $("#RestrictionsEditor").data("kendoEditor").bind("select", function(e){
    //show toolbar on selection
    $("#RestrictionsEditor").closest(".k-editor").find(".k-editor-toolbar").show();
  });

  //bind the blur event
  $("#RestrictionsEditor").on("blur", function(e){
    //hide toolbar
        $("#RestrictionsEditor").closest(".k-editor").find(".k-editor-toolbar").hide();
    });

});
</script>
```